# Ideal way to deploy SSL to blades/chassis

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, dell-poweredge, hardware, blade-server

I have about 14 Dell M1000e chassis and corresponding 224 blades.  I just received a wildcard SSL cert, but don't want to manually visit each administrative page to upload the cert/key.  I understand the racadm command can do this for me, but the documentation falls a bit short.  Is anyone willing to help me out a bit?  I do not have any of the tools available from Dell installed on my workstation or servers, but have access to them if needed.

Comment: `racadm help sslcertupload`?

Comment: It doesn't let me upload my own private key.

Comment: As I read and understand the documentation, no, that is correct. It will only work when you sign a CSR generated with `racadm sslcsrgen`

Comment: Ask me next week. :P I'm about to try and figure this out myself.

Comment: I don't know your product specifics but there are generic ways to automate any operation. You can try expect to automate tasks on the comand line. You can use curl or if you know some language some http library to interact with a web interface. Also you can use selenium to record and run http sessions.
Not really as easy as you want but for 224 blades it's worth it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of `racadm` commands that you need is [`sslkeyupload`](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/smdrac3/idrac/idrac32modular/en/clr/html/racadmsu.htm#wp75558) and [`sslcertupload`](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/smdrac3/idrac/idrac32modular/en/clr/html/racadmsu.htm#wp84791). On a Dell M1000e these should be run using the `idracadm` tool (the ssh interface does not allow you to upload files). On other Dell servers you would have to use the tool corresponding to the (iD)RAC version, i.e. `racadm4`, `racadm5`, `idracadm`, or `idracadm7`.

Something like `idracadm sslkeyupload -t 1 -f path/to/key.pem` and `idracadm sslcertupload -t 1 -f path/to/wildcard-cert.pem` should do the trick for you.

[The iDRAC documentation](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/smdrac3/idrac/idrac32modular/en/clr/html/racadmsu.htm) has more information about these commands.